# How do I get the table key id from a group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query:

```
SELECT ppa.Policy_ID
, (SELECT MAX(ppa2.Deactivated_Date) FROM Policy_Postage_Account ppa2 
         WHERE ppa.Policy_ID = ppa2.Policy_ID) AS maxDate
FROM Policy_Postage_Account AS ppa
WHERE ppa.Active = 0 
GROUP BY ppa.Policy_ID
ORDER BY maxDate
```

and returns the following:

```
Policy_ID   maxDate
6416        2014-06-19 11:14:50.890
3428        2014-06-19 11:17:55.760
8127        2014-06-19 12:02:06.223
8115        2014-06-19 12:02:56.223
7651        2014-06-20 09:31:30.193
```

This most of the information I need but I also need the id column from this table.  So if the primary key column is Policy_Post_ID as INT, I need the following results:

```
Policy_ID   maxDate                       Policy_Post_ID
6416        2014-06-19 11:14:50.890       2
3428        2014-06-19 11:17:55.760       5
8127        2014-06-19 12:02:06.223       66
8115        2014-06-19 12:02:56.223       567
7651        2014-06-20 09:31:30.193       9
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add data? Where is the policy_post_id coming from? Also, have you considered 'Select ppa.Policy_ID, Max(ppa2.Deactivated_Date) as maxDate From...'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that these columns are in a single table and which contains multiple deactivation dates.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Policy_ID ORDER BY Deactivated_Date DESC) ID
        , Policy_Post_ID
        , Policy_ID
        , Deactivated_Date
    FROM Policy_Postage_Account
    WHERE ppa.Active = 0
)
SELECT
    Policy_Post_ID
    , Policy_ID
    , Deactivated_Date
FROM CTE
WHERE ID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For your existing query you don't need a subquery to get these results. The following query should return the same result:

```
SELECT ppa.Policy_ID, MAX(ppa.Deactivated_Date) as maxDate
FROM Policy_Postage_Account AS ppa
WHERE ppa.Active = 0 
GROUP BY ppa.Policy_ID
ORDER BY maxDate
```

Now for getting the value of Policy_Post_ID you can enclose the above query as a temp table and use the Policy_ID (I assume that's your primary key) to find the Policy_Post_ID.

```
SELECT temp.Policy_ID, temp.maxDate, PPA1.Policy_Post_ID from
(SELECT ppa.Policy_ID, MAX(ppa.Deactivated_Date) as maxDate
FROM Policy_Postage_Account AS ppa
WHERE ppa.Active = 0 
GROUP BY ppa.Policy_ID
ORDER BY maxDate) temp 
left join Policy_Postage_Account PPA1
on temp.Policy_ID = PPA1.Policy_ID
```